# visibility issues with IE9 using jquery to add item to listbox

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, internet-explorer-9

I am adding an item to a listbox from an input textbox.  Things work fine in chrome and firefox, however when I click the button to add the text to the listbox in IE9 the item gets added but it is not visible.  WHen I click my save button the item i added shows up in the collection, it just doesnt view in the listbox.

below is my jquery:

```
$('#addToListBox1').click(function () {
var textValue = $('input[name=classIdInput]').val();

$('#listbox1').append(
    new Option( 
        textValue,
        textValue
    ));
});
```

wierd behavior for IE9... any ideas why the added text to the listbox has a position though you cant see it?
thx

Comment: Please show the associated HTML.

Comment: this is an MVC 4 app.  what in particular do you want to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tuens out I needed to add a meta tag in my _layout file:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```